# i try to use select min(select count()) but it doesn't work

Tags: mysql, sql, count, min

i want to get the room having the smallest quantity of emp but it doesn't work

[image]

here is the source:

https://github.com/kamenrider1604/testSQL.git

thank you so much!!

Comment: *i try to use select min(select count())* Nested aggregate functions not allowed. Use subquery, or sorting and limitation.

Comment: Provide both query text and error message as text, not as picture. Provide sample data as textual code or online fiddle, not as a link to git folder.

Comment: Please do **not** post code as images. See here for more details why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551

Answer (score 1):

Use

```sql
SELECT COUNT(..) AS `count`, ..
FROM ..
ORDER BY `count` ASC LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work for you

```
SELECT departments.dep_id, 
       dep_name, 
       dep_address, 
       dep_phone, 
       COUNT(employee.dep_id) 
FROM   employees, 
       departments 
WHERE  employees.dep_id = departments.dep_id 
GROUP  BY employee.dep_id 
HAVING COUNT(employee.dep_id) = (SELECT MIN(min_dep.min) 
                                 FROM   (SELECT COUNT(employees.dep_id) 
                                         FROM   employees 
                                         GROUP  BY employees.dep_id) AS min_dep) 
;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  SELECT MIN(SELECT COUNT(dep_id) FROM employees GROUP BY dep_id) FROM employees
```

This subquery is not correct.
You can not select min() from employees. If you want to find min('count'), you need to select from your subquery:

```
SELECT MIN (count) FROM (SELECT COUNT (dep_id) AS count FROM employees GROUP BY dep_id)
```

*And you don't have to specify the table name in the subquery if it's the only one in there.

Your question is not really helpful here. Because there are other, easier ways to implement what you asked in your question, such as @Akina 's answer, but, by looking at your code, it seems like you are trying to accomplish something a little different. If the above is not what you are trying to do, then there is only one other thing I can think of :

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT a.*, MIN (dep_count) OVER () dep_count_min
          FROM (SELECT departments.dep_id,
                       dep_name,
                       dep_address,
                       dep_phone,
                       COUNT (employee.dep_id)
                           OVER (PARTITION BY employee.dep_id)
                           AS dep_count
                  FROM employees, departments
                 WHERE employees.dep_id = departments.dep_id) a) b
 WHERE a.dep_count = b.dep_count_min
```

*I haven't worked on MySql yet, so all of the above has been implemented in Oracle. I don't think there will be much of a difference in basic SQL, but you can try to write the MySql version of the above query if there are any problems with it.
I hope this will be of help to you.